# Trying to port over ruby script to a rails application, getting uninitialized constant error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I am not very experienced with rails, but I have used it for several apps before.  This app is different because I want to port over a ruby script to a rails app and I am running into several problems, I'm fairly certain I'm going about it the wrong way so wanted to ask S.O. some advice.

The script generates some equations, and I want the controller to just call a helper (or something) to generate the equations list with my script, then pass them on as JSON or something that I can play around with using JS in the view.  I tried simply copying the script files over to the helpers folder, but when I try to initialize them via a new route I made in the controller, it gives this error: NameError (uninitialized constant UsersController::EquationSettings).  I think it may be expecting my model to include all of these objects.

**Code snippet:**

The new controller action is in the users_controller (it has its own route now - wanted it to just pass the equation_list and the user to the view where I will handle all the display):

```
def list_equations
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    equation_settings = EquationSettings.new 10
    equation_list_generator = EquationList.new equation_settings
    @equation_list = equation_list_generator.generate

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user, json: @equation_list }
    end
  end
```

**Folder structure:**
app/controllers/users_controller.rb (the controller noted above)
app/helpers/equation_helpers/(EquationSettings, and EquationList rb files are here)

Once this @equation_list gets passed to the view, I just want to be able to access it like any other JSON hash.  Wide open to any suggestions, if it seems I'm going about this completely the wrong way please try to point me in the right direction.  Appreciate the time of all the readers,

--Anthony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing from your code snippet, you may need to change your approach. A few suggestions/pointers:

1. It looks like you're trying to use a helper *class*, but in Rails, helpers should be **modules**, not to instantiate but to simply use their methods in the view. For example, in `app/helpers/stark_helper.rb` you would want to have:

   ```
   module StarkHelper
     def use_honor
       # winter is coming
     end
   end
   ```

   That would make `use_honor` available in your view.
2. Helper methods automatically become available in the *view*, but not the controller. To use helper methods in a controller (*not recommended; doing so would violate the MVC pattern*) **you need to explicitly include the helper** in the controller class, e.g.:

   ```
   class BaratheonController < ApplicationController
     include BaratheonHelper

     # stuff
   end
   ```
3. When auto-loading project files, such as helpers, **Rails *expects* folder structure and file names to reflect the names of modules and classes defined therein**. For example, Rails would not load your file if in `app/helpers/lannister.rb`, you had defined `module LannisterHelper`; you would need to change that file name to `lannister_helper.rb`. (`lannister_helper.rb` -> `LannisterHelper`)
4. Another important facet of the auto-loading I mentioned is that **sub-folders are expected to reflect sub-classes and sub-modules**. So if you had `app/helpers/greyjoy_helper/greyjoy_boat_names.rb`, that file would need to have this definition:

   ```
   module GreyjoyHelper
     module GreyjoyBoatNames
       # stuff
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, this answer put me on the right track (i.e. to get away from using helpers for this concept).  I ended up making the script objects models (without any db representation) and simply constructing the object in the controller from those models before rendering the view.  Seems to be working well.